# LINQ get two records from each record

Tags: linq

I have a list of objects of this type:

```
MyObject
  .StartDate
  .EndDate
  .Number
```

For each object I want to return two objects of:

```
NewObject
  .Date
  .Number
```

In which in one object the Date will be EndDate and Number.
The other object the Date will be the StartDate and the Number will be the negative Number

Comment: Is `NewObject` a class or an anonymous type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyObjects.SelectMany(o => new[] { 
    new NewObject { Date = o.EndDate, Number = o.Number },
    new NewObject { Date = o.StartDate, Number = -o.Number } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from myObject in MyObjects
              select new NewObject { Date = myObject.StartDate, Number = -myObject.number }).Concat
             (from myObject in MyObjects
              select new NewObject { Date = myObject.EndDate, Number = myObject.number });
```

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance It's O(2n). Like yours.

Comment: Concat has to iterate over it too.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Mine is O(2*n), yours is O(n*2)! We do exactly the same thing but in a different order.

Comment: Cedric, let's see. You iterate over MyObjects twice. O(2n). Then, Concat also needs to iterate through both of them. O(4n). It's even higher than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from o in MyObjects
        select new {
            NewObject1 = new NewObject(){
                Date = o.StartDate,
                Number = -o.Number
            },
            NewObject2 = new NewObject(){
                Date = o.EndDate,
                Number = o.Number
            }
        };
```